# Multiple Arrays

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to access/store multiple arrays or data which could be compared against and return a value to ensure a program is faster?

I will have two variables with multiple possibilities I want to compare these two variables to all the possibilities and return a value but that will slow down the speed of the app is there a way to do it faster?

Comment: Sorry, but what you're asking doesn't make a lot of sense. If you update your question and let us all know what you're trying to achieve you should hopefully get some answers. (The more effort you put into writing a question, the more effort people will put into answering it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to check for existence of an object within a *set*. Sets have a very fast look-up time but do not retain the order of the objects. They are particularly useful for checking whether a value is within a particular set of values. For example, the following snippet acquires a string of text from the user and ensures that it is either `@"Abc"`, `@"Def"`, or `@"Ghi"`. This trivial case involves only three elements but of course you can easily add more.

```
NSSet *possibleValues = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Abc", @"Def", @"Ghi", nil];

NSString *userProvidedInput = /* obtain from user somehow */;

if ([possibleValues containsObject:userProvidedInput])
{
    NSLog(@"The user provided correct input!");
}
```

`NSSet` objects can contain any `NSObject` subclass, including `NSString`, `NSNumber`, etc. If you have a lot of elements in the set, consider storing them in a plist file (use an array), and use something like:

```
[NSSet setWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"some.plist"]];
```